# How to generate datetime.now() in airflow exactly one time

Tags: python, datetime, airflow

I'm getting error when I am trying to generate unique name based on `name + current date`.

```
NAME = 'name-{timestamp}'.format(timestamp=datetime.now())
```

But every task instance generate `datetime.now()` again and `NAME` become different for each tasks.

```
task1 = CustomOperator(
    task_id='task-1',
    name = NAME,
    ...
)

task2 = CustomOperator(
    task_id='task-2',
    name = NAME,
    ...
)
```

Inside of `task1` and `task2` `NAME` will be different. I need `NAME` to be unique and global accessed from task instances in the DAG. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post some code (a [mre]) showing the situation you have. As it stands now, your question is rather unclear.

Comment: Why do you want that type of dynamic name? That will run in every heartbeat of the DAG bag check, so will generate huge amount of tasks (not good for the metadata DB).

Comment: This seems like something of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airflow tasks are expected to be static or slowly changing. Airflow parse the DAG file every `min_file_process_interval` (default 30 seconds) - Which means that every 30 seconds you will create a new task - which probably won't even run.

It's really hard to understand why you want to create tasks like that as you did not explain your use case but if you need dynamic task you can do it as:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    DummyOperator(task_id='{0}'.format(i))
```

**EDIT:** now that you edit your question and explained better. The name parameter is some custom parameter of your Operator. it can be whatever you want. What you can do:

```
timestamp = datetime.now()
for i in range(1, 3):
    task_id = f'task_{i}'
    CustomOperator(task_id=task_id, name=f'{task_id}_{str(timestamp)}')
```

Note that while this will give you unique values it will be hard to for you track them. A better and more Airflowy way to do it is using `{{ execution_date }}` that is assuming `name` is [templated](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#macros-reference) field:

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    task_id = f'task_{i}'
    CustomOperator(task_id=task_id, name=f'{task_id}_{{{{ execution_date }}}}')
```

or you can use the `{{ task_instance_key_str }}` macro which is a unique, human-readable key to the task instance formatted `{dag_id}__{task_id}__{ds_nodash}`

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    task_id = f'task_{i}'
    CustomOperator(task_id=task_id, name='{{ task_instance_key_str }}')
```

Answer (score -1):

As [Elad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832812/2954547) and the other commenters suggested, you probably *don't* want this. Maybe you should be generating and logging/emitting this information in the `execute` method.

Nevertheless, this is a *very* common "gotcha" for programming newbies across various domains, tasks, and programming languages, so I think it's worth showing the pattern here if only for pedagogical purposes.

The answer is simple: compute the time *once*, and save it in a variable. That's it. It's that easy. This is literally what variables are for.

I also strongly suggest explicitly formatting the timestamp using the `datetime.strftime` method, instead of relying on `str()` to do it for you implicitly. Blindly `str`-ifying things is another classic newbie mistake.

Finally, *use timezone-aware datetimes*, and *use UTC*. Don't think too hard about it. Just do it. You'll thank me later.

Complete example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from typing import Any
if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    from typing import Dict
else:
    Dict = dict

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator


# Define a custom operator

class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
    """A custom Airflow operator that doesn't really do anything."""
    def __init__(self, task_id: str, name: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def execute(self, context: Dict[str, Any]) -> int:
        print(
            f'Hello, I am {self.name}, '
            f'and I am executing Task ID {self.task_id}.'
        )
        return len(context)


# Pre-compute the time, making sure to use UTC.
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

# Format the time, unambiguously.
now_fmt = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S%z')

# Another option for formatting.
# See:
# * https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat
# * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
# * https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339
# now_fmt = now.isoformat()

# Use the formatted time string as many times as you need.
with DAG(...) as dag:
    task1 = MyOperator(
        task_id='task-1',
        name = f'task-1_{now_fmt}',
        ...
    )

    task2 = MyOperator(
        task_id='task-2',
        name = f'task-2_{now_fmt},
        ...
    )
```